# HTML table row count after ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, html-table

Can I achieve this even more simpler way?
Here I have my requests populated in a html table... 
My table is like:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
request number
</td>
<td align="center">
approve
</td>
<td align="center">
reject
</td>
<td align="center">
query
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

As you can see I have a single row only in my html code...But after the ajax call my table is populated with several rows of requests..

Now after this is done I have to get the count of table rows and show it in my `<h2>pending requests(<span></span>)</h2>`

LIKE :
pending requests(9)...where 9 is the number of pending requests.

Comment: could you post the code you are using to get the pending requests

Comment: its an complicate code..i will decribe u instead..
I have written a service to fetch those pending requests and called the service through ajax..

Comment: does that suffice or still u want the code ??

Comment: just the javascript ajax code will suffice - as in the call you are making

Comment: Are you just wanting the javascript code to count the number of rows in the table?

Comment: well not exactly..bcoz now wen i try to count the table rows it returns 1...bcoz as u can see i have only one <tr> element..but mu table expands after the ajax call..so i gotta count the rows nd udate it in the span... u got it pete ???

Comment: urlToHandler = 'http://localhost/WcfService/Service1.svc/requests';
 
$.ajax({
                url: urlToHandler,
    data:JSON.stringify({login:{"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}}),
                type: 'POST',
    dataType:"json",
       contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data) {

Comment: now that succes part i have to complete...

Comment: Could you post what the returned json looks like - and I should be able to put together what the success function should look like

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to get the number of rows in the DOM

```
var noOfRows = $('table tr').length;
```

**UPDATE**

so assuming a json structure of

```
{"responses":
 [
  {
   "title":"Title 1",
   "message":"This is message 1"
  },
  {
   "title":"Title 2",
   "message":"This is message 2"
  }
 ]
}
```

And assuming an ajax call like the following:

```
$.ajax({ 
 url: urlToHandler, 
 data:JSON.stringify(
 {login:
  {"loginid":userid,"reqType":"R"}
 }), 
 type: 'POST', 
 dataType:"json", 
 contentType: 'application/json', 
 success: function(data) { 
  $.each(data.responses, function(i,data){
   var newRow = $('<tr><td>' + data.title + '</td><td>' + data.message + '</td></tr>')
   $(newRow).appendTo('table');
  };
 };
});
```

Now if you count the number of rows with

```
var noOfRows = $('table tr').length;
```

You should get an answer of more than 1 Row

Comment: that returns the value as 1 as i have given only one <tr> in my code...but wat i want is after ajax call the table expands...i want that count to be displayed

Comment: Then when you add the data from the ajax method to the table, insert rows like $('table').append($('<tr><td>' + data.obj + '</td></tr>')), with data.obj being the json you want to add into each field.

Comment: Made update as above to show how to add json result to the table